# Why form not support put method?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form when I update user data. When I press button update show me error `The PUT method is not supported for route customers/5/edit. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`. I check my code but I can't find error.

route

```
Route::post('store', 'App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@store')->name('customers.store');

Route::get('/{customer}/edit', 'App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@edit')->name('customers.edit');

Route::put('/{customer}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@update')->name('customers.update');
```

controller

```
public function edit(Customer $customer)
{
    return view('edit', compact('customer'));
}

public function update(Customer $request, $id)
{
    $customers = Customer::find($id);
    $customers->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
    $customers->last_name = $request->input('last_name');      
    $customers->update();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

view

```
<form action="{{ route('customers.store') }}" method="post">
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">
            <input type="text" id="form4Example1" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->first_name }}"/>
            <label class="form-label" for="form4Example1">First name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-outline mb-4">
            <input type="text" id="form4Example1" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->last_name }}"/>
            <label class="form-label" for="form4Example1">Last name</label>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: You can't find the error? `Route::get('/{customer}/edit')` show me where the `put` is :)

Comment: @dbf no-one, so far, has voted to close the question

Comment: It's working exactly as you have defined it. You have `Route::get('/{customer}/edit', ...)`, so `PUT` (or `POST`)-ing to that route will not work. Also, the form you included in your question is the `POST` to `customers.store`; please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75110864/edit) to include the form for `PUT` to `customers.update`.

Comment: @TimLewis you can't send a `PUT` from a HTML form though (reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method)

Comment: @ADyson I can see the future!

Comment: @ADyson I know, you use `POST`, and `@method('PUT')` in Laravel  It's all in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: @dbf I appreciate the comment, but no one here is being "not nice"; downvotes and close votes are not personal (or shouldn't be taken personally). I didn't downvote here, but I can understand why someone did; the error is obvious when looking at the code, or if the asker has read the documentation, and the code posted is not being used to generate the error; that is the `POST` form for `customer.store`, not `customers.update`...

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks  - not being a Laravel user specifically, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

Because your put end-point is called `customers.update` not `customers.store`.

Your form action should be:

```
action="{{ route('customers.update', [ 'id' => $customer->id ]) }}"
```

Also take a look at [Method Spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#form-method-spoofing).

On a side note, you would be better off using [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers) to better enforce the CRUD standard.
You can use [Partials](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes) to trim down the full CRUD spec of a resource.

Comment: `method="PUT"` is wrong: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#form-method-spoofing, it would be `method="POST"`, with `@method('PUT')` after the `<form>` element.

Comment: Also, `route('customers.update')` expects a `/{customer}`, so it would be `action="{{ route('customers.update', $customer) }}"` (or similar)

Comment: @TimLewis You could, I mean .. I'm not trying to convince you or something, but .. you could answer this question :D

Comment: @dbf I know, but when you've been on SO for as long as I have, you start to leave a lot more comments instead of answers. Also, Marc has taken the time to write one, why would I then write my own with fixes for theirs? _That_ would be "being mean", as people would then have to downvote this answer, etc. I'm commenting so they update their answer, so I can then vote it up.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax reminder @TimLewis, I clearly gone rusty.

Answer (score 0):

Route method:

```
   Route::put('customers/update/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@update')->name('customers.update');
```

Blade Logic

```
 <form action="{{ route('customers.update',[$customer->id]) }}" method="post">
        @method('PUT')
        @csrf
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">
            <input type="text" id="form4Example1" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->first_name }}"/>
            <label class="form-label" for="form4Example1">First name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-outline mb-4">
            <input type="text" id="form4Example1" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->last_name }}"/>
            <label class="form-label" for="form4Example1">Last name</label>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Controller Logic:

```
public function edit(Customer $customer)
{
    return view('edit', compact('customer'));
}

public function update(Customer $request, $id)
{
    $customers = Customer::find($id);
    $customers->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
    $customers->last_name = $request->input('last_name');      
    $customers->update();
    return redirect('/');
}
```